# Pandas: Reshaping dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a panda's related question. My dataframe looks something like this:

```
  id val1 val2
0  1     0    1
1  1     1    0
2  1     0    0
3  2     1    1
4  2     1    1
5  2     1    0
6  3     0    0
7  3     0    1
8  3     1    1
9  4     1    0
10 4     0    1
11 4     0    0
```

I want to transform it into something like:

```
             a         b        c
   id     a0   a1   b0   b1   c0   c1
    1     0    1    1    0    0    0
    2     1    1    1    1    1    0
    3     0    0    1    1    1    1
    4     1    0    0    1    0    0
```

I thought of something like adding a sub_id column that is enumerated cyclically by a, b and c and then do an unstack of the frame. Is there an easier/smarter solution?

Thanks a lot!

Tim

Comment: what defines ABC, the id column?

Comment: The number of entries in the id column per entity. So for example the first row for id 1 has letter a, the second row has b, the third has c. Then it starts all over with the next id which also has a, b and c and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible solutions:

Start from reformatting values for each *id* into a single row:

```
res = df.set_index('id').groupby('id').apply(
    lambda grp: pd.Series(grp.values.flatten()))
```

For now the result is:

```
    0  1  2  3  4  5
id                  
1   0  1  1  0  0  0
2   1  1  1  1  1  0
3   0  0  0  1  1  1
4   1  0  0  1  0  0
```

Then set proper column names:

```
res.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [(x, x + y) for x in list('abc') for y in list('01')])
```

The finale result is:

```
    a     b     c   
   a0 a1 b0 b1 c0 c1
id                  
1   0  1  1  0  0  0
2   1  1  1  1  1  0
3   0  0  0  1  1  1
4   1  0  0  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

If possible numbers instead `abc` is use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and last sorting second level with [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html):

```
g = df.groupby('id').cumcount()

df = df.set_index(['id', g]).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1).swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
print (df)
      0         1         2     
   val1 val2 val1 val2 val1 val2
id                              
1     0    1    1    0    0    0
2     1    1    1    1    1    0
3     0    0    0    1    1    1
4     1    0    0    1    0    0
```

If want `a,b,c` values is possible generate dictionary from `string.ascii_lowercase` and `rename` columns:

```
import string

d = dict(enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase))
df = df.rename(columns=d)
print (df)
      a         b         c     
   val1 val2 val1 val2 val1 val2
id                              
1     0    1    1    0    0    0
2     1    1    1    1    1    0
3     0    0    0    1    1    1
4     1    0    0    1    0    0
```

Solution for rename both levels is first create default columns names by range after `set_index`:

```
g = df.groupby('id').cumcount()
df = df.set_index(['id', g])
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
df = df.unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1).swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
print (df)
    0     1     2   
    0  1  0  1  0  1
id                  
1   0  1  1  0  0  0
2   1  1  1  1  1  0
3   0  0  0  1  1  1
4   1  0  0  1  0  0
```

And last in list comprehension set new values:

```
import string

d = dict(enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(d[a], f'{d[a]}{b}') for a, b in df.columns])
print (df)
    a     b     c   
   a0 a1 b0 b1 c0 c1
id                  
1   0  1  1  0  0  0
2   1  1  1  1  1  0
3   0  0  0  1  1  1
4   1  0  0  1  0  0
```

Comment: nice better than my method using itertools and cycle !